# SAT Prep Triangle Equation

Tags: geometry, triangles

I got this problem from my teacher and don't know how to solve, could someone please help?

(SAT Prep) In △ABC, ∠B = 90°, BH = AH, and the ratio of m∠A to m∠C is 1:2. Find m∠BHA?

```
    A. 100°
    B. 90°
    C. 120°
    D. 60°
```

[image: Triangle]

I know that m∠A = 30°, and that m∠C = 60°

Comment: Use the fact that $\triangle BAH$ is isosceles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\triangle BAH$ is isosceles because it has two equal sides.

This means that $m(\angle BAH) = m\angle ABH$ because of base angle theorem.

Then, $m\angle BHA = 180 - (m(\angle BAH) + m(\angle ABH))$ (because the sum of the measures of the angles in a triangle is $180$)

But since $m(\angle BAH) = m(\angle ABH) = 30$, we simply have

$m(\angle BHA) = 180 - (30 + 30) = 120$

Comment: Please use 
[MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
to format math on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let us denote $$\angle{AHB}=\beta$$ and$$\angle{ACH}=\gamma$$. Since we have $AH=HB$ we get
$$\beta=\pi-2\alpha$$ and $$\alpha+\gamma=\frac{\pi}{2}$$ since we have $$2\alpha=\gamma$$ we get $$\alpha=30^{\circ}$$ and $$\beta=120^{\circ}$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know enough math to understand this answer yet.

Comment: @BeastCoder2 The solution of Dr. Sonnhard is the most simplified version of this problem ever. Out of couriosity, in which grade do you read? Then you must learn because there is no age of learning.

Comment: @AnirbanNiloy Given the level of the question being asked, it is in my experience that anyone asking these types of questions is not likely to have a good understanding on the relationship between radians and degrees. While Dr. Sonnhard's answer is incredibly simple to anyone with significant experience in Math, right from the start it makes use of radian measure by letting $\beta = \pi - 2\alpha$. While this is completely equivalent to saying $\beta = 180 - 2\alpha$, this very likely isn't obvious to beginning students, and neither is the implicit conversion from radians to degrees at the end

Comment: @user516079 I haven't enough experience yet to understand your comment!! I thought all relaionship were confined within degrees instead of using radians. I never noticed such an equation $\beta = \pi-2\alpha$.  for your better explanation.